# Googleboot keep crawling non-existing page, not my actual page

Tags: wordpress, googlebot, google-crawlers

I started to build my website 6 months ago.

- Since I started until now for 6 months. Googlebot keep crawling non-existing page on my site. Googlebot randomly generates those links. They accessed to hundreds to thousand of them a day.
- I have verified it is a googlebot.
- Since day one, I left those non-exist pages with a 404 header.
- 6 months later, thing didn't change a bit. Googlebot still crawls the non-existing random generated page at the same rate.

The structure of the link non-existing page is mydomain/installa/{random-string}

example:

mydomain/installa/jfjdk-uru-gy-kfjurru

mydomain/installa/jfj-uru-wed-iehf72

mydomain/installa/dsds-rw3-wwewed-2332jh

Please note I do not use a /installa/   directory on my site either in the back-end folder or on the site url.

The problem is when I posted a actual post on my website. That post would take forever to get indexed by discovering by googlebot.

If I manually submitted my post to google console to get index, that is a different topic and my page got indexed. But I suspect all my issue fall under the above issues I described.

Can anyone help me or point me to the right direction on what going on? Is there something wrong on my site that potentially trigger the /installa/?

is there any Wordpress plugin that I can use to track how googlebot access my site?

Please help me to solve this issue, this issue seems to affect my site ranking at the moment.

Thanks

Comment: Since this is a SEO issue you might want to ask here instead: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a noindex tag to those pages.  Additionally, remove them from your sitemap.

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with my website. In my case all these random pages started with `/?` in naming, so we decided to exclude them from index in robots.txt by `Disallow: /?*`

Comment: Please don't add *Me too* as answers. It doesn't actually provide an answer to the question. If you have a different but related question, then [ask](/questions/ask) it (reference this one if it will help provide context). If you are interested in this specific question, you can [upvote](/help/privileges/vote-up) it, leave a [comment](/help/privileges/comment), or start a [bounty](/help/privileges/set-bounties) once you have enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).